# Can I use full ALM and ticket tracking with Git in TFS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, alm, azure-artifacts

I have worked on many projects using TFS for source control and full ALM which included ticket level task, feature and bug tracking.

I have also used Git with VSO but never seen a project using TFS with task, feature and bug tracking when Git is used as the source control option.

Is this possible and simple to set up, and use full ALM without any tricky steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can link work items to commits by including a hash mark followed by the work item. Ex: "Fixed bug #1234". You can also enforce commits being linked to commits with a [branch policy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-sep-18-vso.aspx).

Comment: An interesting link that could help on the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/overview/alm-devops-feature-index